# Value error: numpy.loadtxt could not convert string to float

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph but it is impossible to correctly read the data under text form: I receive the message "Value error: could not convert string to float".

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y,x = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Downloads\\XRDdata.txt', unpack = True, delimiter = ';')

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title('Diffractogramme de la substance KNO3')
plt.ylabel('Intensité (u.a.)')
plt.xlabel('Angle 2θ (°)')

plt.show()
```

My data looks like this:

```
19.04;24.5    
19.37;11.57    
23.57;100    
23.84;55.4    
27.74;1.7    
29.06;5.69    
29.44;65.53    
32.38;33.95    
32.44;7.54    
33.09;19.97    
33.68;36.61    
33.87;48.58    
34.06;24.59    
37.35;8.61    
38.01;4.57    
38.63;9.22    
39.32;2.83    
40.74;1.59    
41.2;52.8    
41.85;25.27    
43.71;11.8    
44.18;21.33    
45.22;2.31    
46.64;21.82    
46.79;9.81    
47.02;7.97    
48.22;2.96    
48.8;1.97    
51.62;1.67    
51.86;3.78    
etc.
```

How can I make it work ? 
Thank you for your consideration of my troubles with this program.

Comment: probably a bad data somewhere. Give a link to your entire file for more help.

Comment: If you try to only load the data that you provide in the question, it works fine. So the reason for the error must be somewhere else in the data file, where you have missing values or a header or footer which does not comply to the data structure `<value>;<value>`. You can try to provide the full data for anyone to check by giving a link to it (possibly upload it to pastebin.com or similar). You can also experiment with [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) which provides much more options than `loadtxt`.

Comment: There is one problem unrelated to the error: `y,x = np.loadtxt(..., unpack = True, ...)` reads the first column into `y` and the second into `x`, so you mix intensity with angle. Use `x,y = np.loadtxt...` instead.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9bnxlMp-BcXMXFIYjBvWlJuM2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the link of my entire data. Thank you all for the quick responses.

Comment: np.genfromtxt works well! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just to keep this question not unanswered:*

The problem comes from the fact that you have a line containing a lot of white spaces (line 64 in this case) in your data.

[image]

One option is of course to manually delete them.
The other option is to use [`np.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) instead of `np.loadtxt()`.

```
x,y = np.genfromtxt('XRDdata.txt', unpack = True,  delimiter = ';' )
```